# Show that $(y-2x+3)^3=(y-x+1)^2$ is a solution of the differential equation $(2x-4y)dx+(x+y-3)dy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to show that 
$$(y-2x+3)^3=(y-x+1)^2$$
is a solution for:
$$(2x-4y)dx+(x+y-3)dy=0$$
what I did so far is:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{4y-2x}{x+y-3}$$
any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(y-2x+3)^3=(y-x+1)^2$

differentiating this we have

$3(y-2x+3)^2(dy-2dx)=2(y-x+1)(dy-dx)$

using the original equation and substituting we have

$3(y-x+1)(dy-2dx)=2(y-2x+3)(dy-dx)$

$(y+x-3)dy+(-4y+2x)dx=0$

$(2x-4y)dx+(y+x-3)dy=0$

$\fbox{}$

Comment: On line 5 you forgot to put $3(y-x+1)^2$

Comment: i substituted $(y-2x+3)^2=\dfrac{(y-x+1)^2}{(y-2x+3)}$ according to line $1$ hence the canceling of $(y-x+1)$ on the RHS

Answer (score 0):

we can make a substitution

$y=t+1,x=z+2$

$\dfrac{dt}{dz}=-\frac{2z+4-4t-4}{t+1+z+2-3}=\dfrac{4t-2z}{t+z}$

let               $   vz=t$

$v+\dfrac{dv}{dz}z=\dfrac{4v-2}{v+1}\\\dfrac{dv}{dz}z=\dfrac{-v^2+3v-2}{v+1}$

$\dfrac{v+1}{v^2-3v+2}dv= \dfrac{3}{(v-2)}dv-\dfrac{2}{(v-1)}dv=-\dfrac{dz}{z}$

$3\ln(v-2)-2\ln(v-1)=-\ln z-\ln c\\\dfrac{(v-2)^3}{(v-1)^2}=\dfrac{1}{zc}$

$(\dfrac{y-1}{x-2}-2)^3(x-2)c=(\dfrac{y-1}{x-2}-1)^2\implies (y-2x+3)^3c=(y-x+1)^2$

$\fbox{}$

Answer (score -1):

Now it's time to abuse notation.

"Cross multiply" to get

$$(x+y-3)\,dy = (4y-2x)\,dx$$

Then re-arrange to get

$$-(4y-2x)\,dx + (x+y-3)\,dy = 0\implies (2x-4y)\,dx + (x+y-3)\,dy = 0$$

Comment: I believe OP is trying to work backward, and you just undid his step

Comment: I suppose with that then, the OP should have been clearer about how they got that $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ term.  I was under the impression that they had done all the necessary implicit differentiation needed for $(y-2x+3)^2 =(y-x-1)^2$ to get to the $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ they wrote in there post; hence why I posted what I did above.

Answer (score -1):

Consider $$ (2x-4y)+\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}(x+y-3)=\frac{(2x-4y)\mathrm dx +(x+y-3) \mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=\frac{0}{\mathrm dx}=0 $$

Comment: how I use the first equation?

Comment: You already have $\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=\frac{4y-2x}{x+y-3}$.  Thus $$ (2x-4y)+\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}(x+y-3)=(2x-4y)+(4y-2x)=0 $$

Comment: Please check what direction is needed. OP seems to be working backward, and you just undid his step